# using object-fit: cover and srcset

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue using object-fit: cover and srcset together. I have the image set to:

```
.banner-fit {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 1300px;
}
```

and the image is using srcset like so

```
<img srcset="
     ./assets/images/media/media-4x.jpg 3200w,
     ./assets/images/media/media-3x.jpg 2400w,
     ./assets/images/media/media-2x.jpg 1600w,
     ./assets/images/media/media-1x.jpg 800w,
 " src="./assets/images/media/media-2x.jpg" alt="Newspapers" class='banner-fit'>
```

The issue is that mobile devices are choosing the image based on the width. For instance a device with a 320 CSS px screen with a density of 2x is choosing the 800px x 344px image. But because of the object-fit:cover the device actually needs a size bigger to display properly (not be blurry). For instance the image on that same device will be 284 CSS px tall, so 568 actually pixels, which means that it needs the 1600px x 688px image.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think using the attribute `sizes` we can specify which image to load when the viewport has certain width. `sizes` defines the media condition based on which the image from `srcset` is used. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-sizes)

Comment: I'm not sure if this addresses my issue. Can you provide an example?